# Change UEFI Variable in Flash

Tags: boot, uefi

I have a NAS (Synology 1817+) on which I want to run custom OS on. Thus I tried to enter the UEFI to change the boot order, only to find out through searching the internet that synology has restricted the access fully.

The Motherboard has a serial debug header, through which I can stop the booting process and interact directly with GRUB v0.97. Chainloading another bootloader from it does not seem to work (output freezes). Other attached mass storage devices are also not recognized (through using the `geometry` in GRUB), except for the drive on which the Synology-made kernel is. Since this drive is accessible (it's a USB drive), we tried putting other kernels in the file of the Synology kernel, but it would not boot, presumably due to "Secure Boot" being enabled.

My Question now is the following: I have read the contents of the UEFI chip, loaded it into UEFITool and would like to change the following entries: `SecureBootEnforce` (currently set to 1) and `BootOrder`. There are also `SecureBoot`, but it is already set to 0, and `PhysicalBootOrder`, which do not know how to use.

Can I just write directly into the binary file, or is the process more complicated than that? Is there a checksum (I think I saw something like that in the UEFI specification) that has to be adjusted, and if so how (or which programs can do that)?